# jQuery only top level list item only

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prevent the default click on a menu item but still have the sub menu items clickable.

My menu structure:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Publications</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Books</a></li>
<li class="noclick menu-item "><a href="">Articles</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Historical-Phenomenological</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Contemporary Theology</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Communal Affairs</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Translations</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

and the jQuery I'm using that disables the click on Articles and all links under it. I just want to disable click on the link for Articles.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.noclick a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting all anchor elements within `noclick`, instead you can target only the children of `noclick` using the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.noclick > a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: PERFECT! Why does that work? Just learning jQuery started last week. What is does the > mean? I see your additional comment now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: @EdBooth when you use `.noclick > a` it targets only the direct descendants of the `noclick` element, in your markup only `Articles` links is targeted.. but when you use `.noclick a` it targets all anchor elements within `noclick` element irrespective of their level